# Query Salesforce retornando data errada

Tags: java, query, spring, apex

No salesforce quando eu rodo a seguinte query `SELECT Data_de_Nascimento__c FROM Account WHERE id = '0013K00000ABC'` ele me retorna `1999-05-29`

No Java, depois que eu monto a integração, eu rodo este algoritmo

```
QueryResult resultado = salesforce.query("SELECT Data_de_Nascimento__c FROM Account WHERE id = '0013K00000ABC'");

SObject[] registros = resultado.getRecords();

for (Object hospedagemSalesforce : registros) {
    Account account = (Account) hospedagemSalesforce;
    int dia = account.getData_de_Nascimento__c().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int mes = account.getData_de_Nascimento__c().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int ano = account.getData_de_Nascimento__c().get(Calendar.YEAR);

    System.out.println(ano + "-" + mes + "-" + dia);
}
```

a saída me da `1999-5-28`

A query sempre me retorna 1 dia a menos, alguém sabe o que isso pode ter causado?

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente a timezone do java e do banco de dados estão diferentes.

Se estiver usando Mysql, para verificar a timezone:

```
select @@session.time_zone
```

Então você pode rodar a aplicação setando a timezone. Por exemplo:

```
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Sofia
```

Comment: Na verdade não estou usando MySql, estou usando SOQL (base de dados salesforce), já encontrei essa mesma resposta sua em outras questões mas não resolveu... mesmo assim obrigado

Answer (score -3):

Opa,Arthur! tudo bem?
Cara,você pode usar Data Literals na Query e ter a data de nascimento correta.
Segue link da documentação:

**https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm**